# How can I resolve this case of "Useless use of a variable in a void context"?

Tags: string, perl, scope, warnings, void

How can I resolve this case of "Useless use of a variable in a void context"?

For example:

```
  my $err = $soap_response->code, " ", $soap_response->string, "\n";
  return $err;
```

I get warnings like "Useless use of a variable in a void context"? Why? How can I resolve it?

Comment: `my $err = "$soap_response->code $soap_response->string\n";`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In case you want to concatenate the arguments, use the `"."` operator or `join`:

```
my $err = $soap_response->code. " ". $soap_response->string. "\n";
my $err = join '', $soap_response->code, " ", $soap_response->string, "\n";
```

Next is why Perl gives you warnings.

You're assigning to a scalar variable `$err`, and the right-hand side of the assignment is evaluated in scalar context.

Binary "`,`" is the comma operator. In scalar context it evaluates its left argument in void context, throws that value away, then evaluates its right argument in scalar context and returns that value.

Evaluating a variable or a constant and throwing that value away is useless. And perl warns you about this.

FYI: Another possible issue with your code:

```
my $err = $soap_response->code, " ", $soap_response->string, "\n";
```

The assignment has higher precedence so that is:

```
(my $err = $soap_response->code), " ", $soap_response->string, "\n";
```

See [Perl operators and precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) and the [Comma operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) for more information.

Comment: Great answer.  But 'the right argument' is a bit ambiguous.   Its assigning the wrong value and not the right one :).  Try, perhaps, 'right-most' or 'final' or 'last' or something.

Comment: I'd really like this answer better if it included mention of the concatenation operator as "this is what you meant".

Comment: This is a better explanation of what went wrong, but codaddict has a better solution.  `join` is just overkill here.  What he really wanted was the concatenation operator, `.`.

Answer (score 16):

I guess you wanted to concatenate the string pieces to form the entire error message, so you'll have to use the dot instead of comma:

```
my $err = $soap_response->code. " ". $soap_response->string. "\n";
```

Comment: @ephemient: That is not at all the same thing as the original code.  Method calls are not hash lookups (even if the method just does a hash lookup, it might change in the future).

Comment: @cjm Those aren't method calls, try it yourself.  `$$_{key}` is `${$_}{key}` is `$_->{key}`, except that the latter is a little more work to interpolate into a string.  `perl -e'$_ = {key=>1}; print $$_{key}, ${$_}{key}, $_->{key}'` ==> 111

Comment: @ephemient, the point is that the original code in the OP *is* using method calls, not hash lookups.

Comment: @friedo @cjm Oh, I *totally* missed that.  Waugh.  `"${\scalar $soap_response->code} ${\scalar $soap_response->string}\n"` but that's actually pretty damn ugly.

Answer (score 3):

```
my $err = join(' ', $soap_response->code, $soap_response->string) . "\n";
```

or, better IMO:

```
return sprintf "%s %s\n", $soap_response->code, $soap_response->string;
```

See [perldoc -f join](http://perldoc.perl.org/function/join.html) and [perldoc -f sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator).

Regarding the warning, see [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) and [this note on the comma operator](http://japhy.perlmonk.org/articles/pm/2000-02.html#1.3).

Comment: +1 for the sprintf version, which is the right way to do this IMO.