# Perl Useless use of private variable in void context

Tags: perl

I looked at [How can I resolve this case of "Useless use of a variable in a void context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342143/how-can-i-resolve-this-case-of-useless-use-of-a-variable-in-a-void-context) and it says to use . to concatenate which is what I did but I still the warning.

Useless use of private variable in void context at /mysz/bin/heer line 79.

```
 43 sub getLog {
 44     opendir(my $dh, $_[0]) || die "can't opendir $_[0]: $!";
 45     my @ooolog = grep {(/^\.oooo_log/)} readdir($dh);
 46     closedir $dh;
 47     return $ooolog[-1];
 48 }

 ...
 79             $ooolog ? ($ooo = $log. "/". &getLog($log)) : $ooo;  <---------
 ...
```

Not quite sure how to fix Useless use of private variable in void context

Anyone know how to fix it?

---

EDIT:

```
78             $ooodata ? ($fl = $fl. "/.ooo_data") : ($fl = $fl. "/.ooo");
```

if its an `? :` issue then why is it not raising the warning at 78?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider what happens when `$ooolog` is false. You end up executing

```
$ooo;  # Useless
```

I think you were going for

```
$ooo = $ooolog ? $log . "/" . &getLog($log) : $ooo;
```

But it's simpler to do

```
$ooo = $log . "/" . &getLog($log) if $ooolog;
```

---

In the added question, you no longer get the warning because

```
$ooo;                  # Useless
```

has been replaced with

```
$fl = $fl. "/.ooo";    # Not useless
```

That said,

```
$ooodata ? ($fl = $fl. "/.ooo_data") : ($fl = $fl. "/.ooo");
```

is much better written as

```
$fl .= $ooodata ? "/.ooo_data" : "/.ooo";
```

If you have an assignment inside of a conditional operator, you are doing something wrong (something suboptimal and/or hard to read).

Answer (score 3):

You've put an expression on line 79, but you don't actually do anything with the result.  Thus, it is useless.

A better (and non-useless) way to write your apparent intent would be:

```
$ooo = $log. "/". &getLog($log) if $ooolog;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just write it as

```
if ($ooolog) { $ooo = $log. "/". &getLog($log) }
```

Or is it part of an expression?

Added answer:

In the second example you have two assignments: if $oodata, either

```
$fl = $fl. "/.ooo_data"
```

or

```
$fl = $fl. "/.ooo"
```

But in the first example, what you have is, if $ooolog, either

```
$ooo = $log. "/". &getLog($log)
```

or

```
$ooo
```

That last `$ooo` is lost, nobody gets its value. It's in a void context, and writing it there is useless. That's what the warning means.

Comment: view added question please